# using the .load() to copy dynamic content

Tags: php, jquery

Good Evening!

i have a page "student_area.php" and it has 10 links (ie 10 subjects) that, when clicked, open a new php page in a new browser tab.

the student_area.php is the landing page for registered users and it stores the "exam_type" of the user in a p element. so, the element 'exam_type' is set after a successful login and the value can be 1 thru 10.

so, if the student clicks the 'math' link, it opens the math.php page in a new window.

i am using javascript for front end and php for server side.

in the math.php, i am trying to use the .load() function to get the value of 'exam_type' from the student_area.php but the load() is not returning the value of the needed element.

it is returning all the static elements but not the dynamic elements such as exam_type.

can anyone guide me please

regards

Comment: Can you use get method such as [url]?exam_type=1

Comment: @star_man yes i am using it but there are other parameters that i dont want users to see what is being passed. [url]?param shows what is being passed in the browser.

Comment: Then, you can use cookie or session.

Comment: @Star_Man am a newbie  and i will be grateful if u cd point me to a good sessions tutorial.

Comment: To make it easier for other users to help you, please include some code to show [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), preferably in the form of a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Comment: @ScottWeldon will do next time. merry xmas!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session or cookie.

```
<!-- first page -->
<?php
  session_start(); 
  $_SESSION['exam_type'] = '1';
?>

<!-- second page -->
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['exam_type']; // it will print 1 

?>
```

See it. 
http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php
http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.php

or javascript

```
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post";  //default post method
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);
    //input type hidden name(key) value(params[key]);
    for(var key in params) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

and call this. `post_to_url('math.php', {'exam_type':'1'});`

In math.php

```
$_POST['exam_type']  //  1
```

Comment: thank u very much!!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck...

Comment: it worked beautufully!!! .... just wanted to say thank u and wish u a merry christmas and happy new year

Comment: Thx, Happy new year too~~~